# Existence of non Borel-measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Consider two functions f,g defined on the unit interval where f is Borel measurable but g is not. The set where f does not equal g has borel measure 0.  I would like to prove that such a function g exists.

I'm not quite sure where to start here... This is not graded homework so either hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The Cantor (middle thirds) set has cardinality $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and Lebesgue/Borel measure $0$. The cardinality of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is $\mathfrak{c}$.